# Enable Multi Tenant Feature in Broadleaf Admin Site

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Dears,

I'm trying to explore Multi Tenant functionality in broadleaf Admin site but I can't find the site management option used in Broadleaf demo videos.

Anyone have this experience can advice how to enable it in the Admin demo site(version develop-6.1)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The multi-tenant and sandboxing features are only available in the commercial version of Broadleaf Commerce. Contact info@broadleafcommerce.com if you are interested in a commercial license.